# dot in name of GET & POST Request data (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.net MVC TryUpateModel or UpdateModel automatically bind HTTP Request (form & query string) as an object property using dot.

For example, `<input type="text" name="Person.first_name">` can be automatically bind to object Person.first_name

The problem is having a dot in Query string and form can cause unknown issue in future. Anyway I can replace this dot delimiter with other character such as '-' and etc?

Answer (score 0):

Passing your dotted id in the Html Attributes will do what you want in Form POSTs at least

Kindness,

Dan

```
<%=Html.TextBox("some.thing", "", new { id = "some.thing" })%>
```